# Why any type is allowed in typescript? where it makes difficult to catch error at compile time

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging

Why **any** type is allowed in typescript. It may generate bugs at runtime, and type **any** makes it difficult to detect bugs at compile-time.
Example:

```
const someValue: string = "Some string";
someValue.toExponential();
```

When I define its type string it shows a compilation error. Because `toExponential()` is not a function for string type data. But when I change its type to **any**.

```
const someValue: any = "string";
someValue.toExponential();
```

It does not show any compile-time error and generate an error at run-time. So, what is the exact use of type **any**? and how to avoid run-time error while using type **any**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid the use of type **any** in typescript because it can cause ambiguity in your code and may lead to run-time errors. Because **any** type means the type will be decided at runtime. Which type of data it contains same will be the type of the variable. Example:

```
let someVariable: any ;
somVariable = 1000;
```

`somVariable`'s type will be read as a number at run-time.

```
somVariable = "string";
```

if `somVariable` contains a string the type will be read as a string at run-time.

The type mismatch error will be generated at run-time if there is a mismatch because the type is decided at run-time of any.

**But sometimes it is easy to use the type *Any*.**
Suppose, you are getting `someValue` from `someFunction()`. You don't know the return type of `someFunction()`, and you don't have to perform type-bound operations on the data. You may use type **any**.

```
const someValue: any = someFunction();
console.log(someValue);
```

You have to be careful using type **any** to avoid run-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

One of the use of `any` type is that, when migrating a large codebase from js to ts, `any` can be used as a stopgap arrangement.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any